# Unable to accept android Licenses for debugging and compiling .NET MAUI

Tags: linux, arch-linux, visual-studio-code, c#

I have tried everything I could. Even the non-recomendable option of starting code as superuser and changing through chmod all the permissions at /opt/android-sdk folder. I also followed the instructions provided by VS Code about deleting and re-accepting the licenses. Everything I thought.

The thing is I actually agree to all licenses from the CLI. However, when accessing from VS Code, It is unable to either accept the licenses nor detect that they are already accepted. And when opening vscode as super user -don't ask me why- it's unable to detect MAUI SDK (but does detect .NET SDK... Mind blown)

I configured correctly the java SDK and the android SDK paths. I also reported a bug through github... I have no idea of what else to do (apart from changing again the permissions of /opt/android-sdk files, for security purposes...)

Anyone developing with C#/MAUI at archlinux (or any other Linux distro, don't care) who solved this deal?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/762003/unable-to-accept-android-licenses-for-debugging-and-compiling-net-maui , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77523732/unable-to-accept-android-licenses-for-debugging-and-compiling-net-maui